# Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync() not asking for permission on Android 5.1

Tags: android, expo

I'm trying to create a React Native app with Expo that needs access to location services. I tried their simple usage in their [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/location/#usage) on a physical Android device. However, a prompt does not show up to access, therefore, I get 'Permission Denied' on the console.

This may be because of my Android Version. If so, is there a way to have access for older Android versions?